# Укромный уголок

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Каково происхождение слова "укромный"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

От слова "у кромки", то есть скраю. Таким образом, это уголок где-то в стороне, на краю.

Answer (score 1):

Древнерусское. Образовано от *укромити* — «отдалить», производного с приставкой у- в значении «в сторону» (как *увести*, *убрать*) от глагола *кромити* — «отдалять, отделять», «перемещать на край».